# Is there a way to display an SSRS Expression in design view of Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, expression

We have been using Visual Studio 2005 for the past 13 years.  We are getting ready to migrate to Visual Studio 2017.  In our Visual Studio 2005 reports, expressions appeared in the report just fine.  However, in Visual Studio 2017, they appear as `<<Exp>>`.

Is there a way to show the actual expression in the design view?  I do not want to have to click on every `<<Exp>>`, open it in the Expression editor just to see it, and selecting an expression and waiting for the pop-over is slow and cumbersome when your report has many expressions.

Here is an example of what Visual Studio 2005 would show in a field of the design view:

```
=Floor((Sum(Fields!internal_talk_duration.Value) + Sum(Fields!internal_received_talk_duration.Value) + Sum(Fields!inbound_talk_duration.Value)) / 3600) & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", (Sum(Fields!internal_talk_duration.Value) + Sum(Fields!internal_received_talk_duration.Value) + Sum(Fields!inbound_talk_duration.Value)), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

Here is an example of what Visual Studio 2017 now shows in that same field:

```
<<Exp>>>
```

From my reading, Microsoft says Complex Expressions display as `<<<Exp>>>`, but they do not offer a way that I could find to show it the old way.  This is what I read about expressions from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-uses-in-reports-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I'd say the answer is a simple No. if you have the Field show directly, it will show the name.. else, everything is shown as <<Exp>>>. You just get used to it!

Comment: Unfortunately, when you have a report with 20 of those fields and you are just looking for a specific one, it makes it hard to find the one.

Comment: I can relate to that frustration.. but it is what it is.. unfortunately

Comment: A suggestion: Open the rdl file with notepad++ or another xml editor and check your expressions there. For changes you can see the field name and change the code from visual studio (or the editor). After changes are made from visual studio notepad++ will ask to reload the file.

Comment: Yeah, we looked at having to edit the XML.  I was hoping there was a better way.  Seems to me, when your software moves forward it should get better at helping the user access things.  Not bury them in multiple menu button clicks and take things away from view :(

Comment: As an alternative, you could right-click the expression, chose "placeholder properties" and specifiy a *label* (=text to be displayed instad of `<<Exp>>`)

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, your suggestion is actually the answer!